# Qt application with QSqlDatabase does not work properly when building it with macdeployqt

Tags: mysql, macos, qt, macdeployqt

In my application I am using a QSqlDatabase to store some information. I did built it successfully with the following command (no errors even with `verbose=3`):

```
macdeployqt AppName.app/ -dmg -qmldir=~/dev/AppName/qml
```

Before that I successfully installed mysql55 using port

```
sudo port install mysql55
```

If I try to run my application it does not crash, but it also does not anything which involves database access.

This is my code for opening a database etc:

```
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlDriver>

const QString DATABASE_NAME = "com.company.program.db";

MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {
    mDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

    #ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
    QString path(QDir::home().path());
    path.append(QDir::separator()).append(DATABASE_NAME);
    path = QDir::toNativeSeparators(path);
    mDB.setDatabaseName(path);           // NOTE: We have to store database file into user home folder in Linux
    #else
    mDB.setDatabaseName(DATABASE_NAME);  // NOTE: File exists in the application private folder, in Symbian Qt implementation
    #endif

    bool notOpened = !mDB.open();

    QMessageBox::critical(0, "MyClass", mDB.lastError().databaseText()); // always is 'out of memory'

    if (notOpened) emit failedToOpen();
    else {
        // some initialization
    }
}

MyClass::~MyClass() {
    mDB.close();
}
```

Has anyone experienced the same issues / a fix for this one?

Note: I am using Mac OS X 10.9 and Qt5.3.2

Comment: after open is failed, try to get and check the error message by calling mDB->lastError()->databaseText()

Comment: Strange thing is it does not emit the signal `failedToOpen`

Comment: Get the error message just after if (!mDB.open()) in the code

Comment: @N1ghtLight I get 'out of memory' exception. How can this happen? I have got only 2 tables, which do not have any entries at the beginning.

Comment: Niklas, search engine should be your best friend ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/18325616/2266412

Comment: Well I just open it in one place, which is the one you see above in my code.

Comment: please update your code with place from where you retrieve this sql error.

Comment: it looks like that you give the wrong path to your database file, you can check existence of the file with static QFile::exists(const QString & fileName) ... try to check the file existence before you set database name.

Comment: I updated my question with the constant (DATABASE_NAME). I mainly took this code from [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Creating_an_SQLite_database_in_Qt). Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: As I wrote above, try to verify is your database file exists by provided path or not. Code looks good, but your database file should be placed in the working directory of the application.

Comment: @N1ghtLight thanks for your help. I managed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the `out of memory` error by executing this code:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_MAC
    QString databaseName = QApplication::applicationDirPath().append("/").append(DATABASE_NAME);
    mDB.setDatabaseName(databaseName);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The Database Drivers are loaded at run-time. You won't get any database-config related errors during the compilation process, if the db-driver paths' are not correct.
The paths' can't even be incorrect, as you build on a machine where Qt is installed.

On Windows this occurs often, when the exe can't access files in plugins\sqldrivers.
Is there something like Linux's 'strace' on MAC? If yes, you could trace, in which paths your exe attempts to find driver plugins.

I always copy the entire plugin directory in installer and deploy it in the root-directory of the executable e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\\plugins

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am on OS X and macdeployqt is doing all the stuff like copying the right directories ;)